# Puppeteer - using await inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I am trying to check if there are specific number of elements with a specific class name. In case they are less than the number, keep scrolling down.

This is the code i used.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
        while (await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9 _gfh3').length < counter) { 
            window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
        }
    });
```

This snippet of code is contained inside an async function.

Unfortuantely i get this error message:

```
C:\pup\test.js:27
        while (await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9 _gfh3').length < counter) {
                     ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The error

You need to mark the function you're passing inside as `async`, an `async` function is only lexically scoped to the function itself.

Any functions you call inside it (like `.forEach` or `evaluate` in this case) need to be marked as `async` themselves (assuming they support it):

```
//            Here
page.evaluate(async () => {
```

#### Fixing the larger issue

In your specific case, you should extract the loop *outside* of the evaluate to avoid timeouts:

```
while(await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9 _gfh3').length < counter) {
  await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
}
```

If your `evaluate` takes too long puppeteer will time out and it is generally preferable to not do expensive stuff inside `evaluate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have no errors with this code! Although you should add another ')' to your code example. Unfortuantely, although i had no errors, the code didn't run correctly. I have a await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'}); snippet afterwards, to see if the code indeed managed to scroll down to the end, until all elemets are there. Unfortunately, the pic was at the beginning of the webpage. It didn't scroll down to the end

Comment: After further testing, i found that await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9 _gfh3').length returns undefined... Is this normal?

Comment: @user1584421 what does `await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9 _gfh3')` return?

Comment: I managed to solve it. I should add another dot to the selector. Although now it scrolls down, until all the elements have loaded, the problem is it never stops scrolling down. After i terminate the application i get this error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()."

So maybe i have to use then or catch in the code above?

Comment: @user1584421 sorry for that error! (that's my fault!) - we've improved the error in newer versions of Node.js to show more useful - you can `--trace-warnings` in the meantime to get a better error stack.

Comment: No worries! Thanks a lot! Could you please take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709049/puppeteer-infinite-scrolling-situation

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
await page.evaluate( async () => {
    while (await page.$$('.Ns6lhs9 _gfh3').length < counter) { 
        window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
    }
});
```

The callback of evaluate needs async prefixed.

Comment: Note that this code is wrong because `page.$$` isn't available inside `evaluate`.