# Puppeteer - infinite scrolling situation

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I wanted to keep scrolling down, until all the elements with a particular classname are loaded in a dynamic HTML environment.

This is the code i used:

```
while ((await page.$$('.xj7')).length < counter) {
 await page.evaluate(() =>
  window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight));
}
```

The problem is that after it loads all the elements, it doesn't stop scrolling. I don't know why is that, as it should exit the while loop.

When i terminate the application, i get this error:

```
(node:5708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.cal
lFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
    at CDPSession.send (C:\node_modules\pupp
eteer\lib\Connection.js:187:29)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:73:75)
    at ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:46:31)
    at Frame.evaluate (C:\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:326:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:5708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 4)
(node:5708) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

As you can see it mentions unhandled promise rejection. Maybe it has to do with the new async function i introduced inside the while loop?

EDIT:
I decided to test the value of the `page.$$('.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w')).length`

I wrote this test code:

```
while ((await page.$$('.xj7')).length < counter) {
 const read = (await page.$$('.xj7')).length;
 console.log(read);
 await page.evaluate(() =>
  window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight));
}
```

The values increased from 12, to 24, then they got stuck at 30! Then when the page has loaded all the elements, the value dropped to 28!

That's why it stucks to this loop. I don't understand while the page has hundreds of these elements, it ranged to these values.

Comment: What is `counter`, and why would you expect the number of `xj7` classes reduce as you scroll down a page?..

Comment: I dont expect it to reduce. Counter is the number of the elements with this particular classname (i know it beforehand). So i keep scrolling down so that the dynamic HTML webpage serves me all the elements with tha classname.

Comment: So why would you expect the loop to end, your basically saying.. while the number of elements of class `xj7` is less the number of elements of class `xj7`, keep scrolling..  So of course it won't end..

Comment: But when all the elements are there, the elements of class xj7 is equal to the counter. And the less than condition is not true. Therefore, it should stop.

Comment: Well in theory it should stop instantly then, as normally unless the website is dynamically adding elements to the DOM as you scroll down,  `page.$$('.xj7')` is going to have the same value from start to end, no matter what you do with scrolling.  How are you calculating counter?

Comment: Can you think of a solution?

Comment: How about just detecting when you have scrolled to the bottom.?

Comment: Can i do that??

Comment: Sure, and easy way is just to keep track of `window.scrollY`, if it doesn't change in your `while` loop you are done..

Comment: But in that case, if i scroll up the Ypos will change and restart the scrolling. It's a hack but not a ermanent solution. I want the loop to end and exit.

Comment: I'm confused, why would you scroll back up?..  What exactly are you trying to do with puppeteer,?..  It's meant as an automation system, you have full control, and have expected behaviour.  I was assuming this scrolling bit, might be for you taking screenshots or something, but now I've no idea what your doing.. :)

Comment: I am trying to load all the elements in a dynamic page. They are loaded with the scroll down.